# High charts no data is displayed

Tags: c#, asp.net, highcharts

I need to display a column highchart.
Data i get using SSE.

Following is my code.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var chart;
    var data = [];

    var myArr;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column',
                events: {
                    load: getData
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'PROJECT DETAILS'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [],
                labels: {
                    rotation: -70,
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'EMPLOYEE COUNT'
                },
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return this.value;
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'column',
                name: 'Project Attendance',
                data: data
            }]
        });
    });

    function getData() {
       // var series = this.series[0];

        if (typeof (EventSource) !== "undefined") {
            var source = new EventSource('GetProjects.aspx');
            source.onmessage = function (event) {
                myArr = JSON.parse(event.data);
                $.each(myArr, function (i, item) {
                    data.push([i, parseInt(item)]);
                });
            };
        }
    }
</script>
```

My json string that i get from **GetProjects.aspx** looks like this

```
{ "12 Aug": 100, "20 Aug": 200, "21 Aug": 40, "22 Aug": 40, "23 Aug": 50, "24 Aug": 0, "25 Aug": 0, "26 Aug": 0 }
```

In the console i get the error:

> ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING.

Is it because there is no data when page is loaded?
Can anyone help me doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't know if this is a type error in the question. But the Json String is incorrect. remove the ";" in the end. See if that helps with something.

Comment: Yes. that is a type error. Updated

Comment: its because on page load you're not loading any data.

Comment: How can i do it there? Can u please help

Comment: Why you cannot load json by $.getJSON() instead of refering to object?

Comment: if i do so then need to use setinterval also.I want to update the highchart when new data is available

Comment: Instead of data.push([i, parseInt(item)]); try to use this.series[0].addPoint([i, parseInt(item)]);